# R CMD check and .RDa Data files

Tags: r, rda

I have data files in the .RDa format under the data sub directory. But, the `R CMD check` command is not recognizing the `load("test.RDa")` command and its failing at this stage and gives the following error:

```
Warning in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :  
cannot open compressed file 'test.RDa', probable reason 'No such file or directory'  
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection  
Calls: load -> readChar  
Execution halted
```

Can you please let me know the reason? Should I give a path specifying from where to load?

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from your data file extension. You could try with `.rda` instead of `.RDa` if your file system is case sensitive ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include data in your package, put it in `mypkg/data/foo.rda` and "load" it via `data(foo)`.  You should also create a `mypkg/man/foo.Rd` file to document the data.

Read more in the [Data in packages section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Comment: Can I just copy a .csv file into the data subdirectory? How to create a .Rd file for that? What should be the /alias and /usage?

Comment: @user602599: please read the documentation.  The *Data in packages* section says that `?data` describes the files formats, including .csv files.  The [Documenting data sets](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-data-sets) section of *Writing R Extensions* answers your 2nd and 3rd questions.  I'm happy to help with areas of the documentation you find confusing, but it seems you haven't tried what's in the manual.

Comment: I copied a test.csv into data sub directory and create a test.Rd file (under man directory) with the following details in the .Rd file: `\name{Raw csv file}  
\docType{data}  
\alias{test}  
\usage{data(read.csv("test.csv")}`   I still get an error while running R CMD check. Can you please tell me what am doing wrong?