# Loading depending packages using .onLoad

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

My package requires ggplot2 package, but I am having trouble to fix the following NOTES that I get when I run R CMD check.

```
no visible global function definition for qplot
'library' or 'require' call not declared from: ggplot2
```

I also have a .onLoad function,

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
.libPaths("~/RLibrary")
require(ggplot2)
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve the errors? Where should I place the onLoad function?

Thank you
San

Comment: Given this question and your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293234/r-cmd-check-and-rda-data-files) you would probably save yourself a lot of trouble if you would closely read [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you should do it like that. It is best to either make your package depend on ggplot2 or import the namespace of ggplot2. Do the in the DESCRIPTION file by adding `Depends: ggplot2` and the second by adding `Imports: ggplot2` in DESCRIPTION and `import(ggplot2)` in NAMESPACE (or be more exact with `importfrom(ggplot2,"somefunction")`.

Alternatively you could set `Suggests: ggplot2` in DESCRIPTION and put a `require("ggplot2")` in any functions that uses it, but I don't like this alot.

See also:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file

EDIT: To be a bit more clear. With `Depends` the package is loaded every time your package is loaded and its functions are all available for the user.

With `Imports` you can use the functions of the package, but the package is not loaded when your package is not loaded (functions are not available to the user).

With `Suggests` the package is not loaded when you load your package and you can't use its functions. You need to declare a `require` somewhere to use them. Basically this can be used to make clear that you use this package somewhere (in an example or so).

It all depends on how you want your users to be able to use the depended package and how important it is for your package. For example, if your package is a frontend to `ggplot2` `Depends` is best, if it does some analysis and has an plot function `Imports` is best.