# How to include dataset in a r-package?

Tags: r, package, cran

I'm trying include dataset in my r-package. So, I puted the `.rda` files in the folder `/data`. In my examples environment I loaded the dataset by the way:

`load("~/mypackage/data/database.rda")`

But, when I submited for CRAN, their reported the follows error:

> Warning in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
> cannot open compressed file '/home/hornik/mypackage/data/database.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Does this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293234/r-cmd-check-and-rda-data-files) help? The official document is Writing R Extensions, [section 1.1.6 Data in packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages). Also, is the package you submitted to CRAN really named `mypackage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error appears because your home folder (`~/`) is not included in the package. Try to use simple:

```
data(database)
```

You can see more details in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages).